# How to extract a word using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex

How do I extract **foo** from the following URL and store it in a varialbe, using regex in php?

```
http://example.com/pages/foo/inside.php
```

I googled quite a bit for an answer but most regex examples were too complex for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('~pages/(.+?)/~', "http://example.com/pages/foo/inside.php", $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there could be multiple solutions, based on what rule you want the `foo` to be extracted. As you didn't specify it yet, I'll just guess that you want to get the folder name of the current file (if that's wrong, please expand your question).

```
<?php
$str = 'http://example.com/pages/foo/inside.php';
preg_match( '#/([^/]+)/[^/]+$#', $str, $match );
print_r( $match );
?>
```

Comment: That's correct, just want the folder name. @stereofrog's answer works. But thanks!

Comment: Well, my answer works for all urls, just in case you need it :) – Btw. you can upvote answers if you approve them (in addition to accepting one final answer).

Answer (score 1):

*If* the first part is invariant:

```
$s = 'http://example.com/pages/foo/inside.php';
preg_match('@^http://example.com/pages/([^/]+).*$@', $s, $matches);
$foo = $matches[1];
```

The main part is `([^/]+)` which matches everything which is *not* a slash (`/`). That is, we're matching until finding the next slash or end of the string (if the "foo" part can be the last).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'http://example.com/pages/foo/inside.php';
$s=parse_url($str);
$whatiwant=explode("/",$s['path']);
print $whatiwant[2];
```